# Solving a differential equation: $x'(z)\sqrt{\frac{2m(H-mgz)}{1+x'(z)^2}}=a$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, euler-lagrange-equation

I'm trying to find that the equation of a particle under the influence of
a gravitationel field is $z(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$.

I'm using the Maupertuis principle (because why not ...):
$\delta\displaystyle{S(x)=\delta\int \sqrt{2m(H-mgz)}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}z}\right)^2}~\mathrm{d}z}=\delta\displaystyle{\int L(z,x') \mathrm{d}z}=0$

Which leads (using the Euler-Lagrange equation) to $\displaystyle{\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}-\frac{d}{\mathrm{d}z}\left(\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial {x}'}\right)=0\Rightarrow \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial x'}=a}$ and finally: 
$\displaystyle{x'(z)\sqrt{\frac{2m(H-mgz)}{1+x'(z)^2}}}=a$.

I know that $x(z)$ must lead to an equation: $z(x)$ being a parabola but I've no idea how to find $x(z)$...

Maybe there is an easiest way to find $z(x)$ using the Euler lagrange equation (with the Maupertuis's principle not the Hamiton's principle) but I can't find it.

Comment: You can actually rearrange to get $x'(z) = \sqrt{\frac{a^2}{2mH-2m^2gz-a^2}}$. From there, just integrate both sides with respect to $z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, rearrange to express $x^\prime$ as a function of $z$. Then you can integrate to get $x$ as a function of $z$.